# Bootstrap dropdown menu in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

here is my question. Thanks for helping me!

**Intent**

I have a page where I need to get a status overview of a, let's say, project. I have a status and a performance property in my model.
I want to show a green circle if they are on Track, red if delayed etc...
I'm using Angular and Bootstrap, so I tryied to create a custom directive that wraps a Bootstrap dropdown and that binds the model property to be updated.
If you want to change the status from "On Track" to "Delayed" you click on the circle, a dropdown opens up, you select the right menu entry, the model is changed and the circle color updated accordingly.

**Issues**

As long as I put 1 directive, evething works fine. When I insert more than one, the last one is the only one that gets updated. If I click on one circle, the menu opens up, but the model that changes is the last one, non the right one.

**Example**

My directive:

```
angular.module("samson", [])
.controller("overviewCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.status = "On track";
    $scope.tsaStatus = "Completed";
    $scope.performance = "Risk of delay";
})
.directive("clickableStatusIcon", function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="dropdown">' +
        '<div class="circle on-track dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"></div>' +
        '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">' +
        '<li role="presentation"><a data-ng-click="onTrack()" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:;">On track</a></li>' +
        '<li role="presentation"><a data-ng-click="riskOfDelay()" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:;">Risk of delay</a></li>' +
        '<li role="presentation"><a data-ng-click="delayed()" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:;">Delayed</a></li>' +
        '<li role="presentation"><a data-ng-click="completed()" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:;">Completed</a></li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>',
        scope: {
            target: '=ngModel',
            name: '@'
        },
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function ($scope, elem, attr) {

            classCleaner = function (newValue) {
                angular.element(elem.children()[0]).removeClass("on-track risk-of-delay delayed complete").addClass(status2ClassMapping[newValue]);
                $scope.target = newValue;
            }

            status2ClassMapping = {
                "On track": "on-track",
                "Risk of delay": 'risk-of-delay',
                "Delayed": "delayed",
                "Completed": "complete"
            };

            $scope.onTrack = function () {
                classCleaner("On track");
            }

            $scope.riskOfDelay = function () {
                classCleaner("Risk of delay");
            }

            $scope.delayed = function () {
                classCleaner("Delayed");
            }

            $scope.completed = function () {
                classCleaner("Completed");
            }

            classCleaner($scope.target);
        }
    }
});
```

You can see an example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Adhara/87zvzx28/)

Could you please provide me with some hints on why that is happening? 
Please note that the code is not that clean and I am aware of that. The string comparison, the text2 css class mapping, etc... is ugly but please focus on the way I define the template and the scope functions. I fear the issue is there but I do not understand why.

Thanks a lot

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add $scope to all functions in directive:

```
$scope.classCleaner
$scope.status2ClassMapping
```

Then it works. Also I suggest you: use ng-repeat to populate your list and use ng-class to change elements class.

Comment: Great, thanks. Actually, only the classCleaner needs to be added to the scope because it acts on the elem so it has to be "contectualized". I will also dig into your suggestions about ng-repeat and ng-class. Thanks a lot! Is there any better way to do that or is that the correct way to use this kind of directive?